# Export of repeated tables in R

Tags: r, testing, printing, statistics, export

I need to do an "automatic", repeated analysis (loop analysis?) that can be easily exported.

I have to analyze a satisfaction survey that includes many sentences. Every participant will answer with a number system from 1 (I am not at all satisfied) to 5 (I am very satisfied).

Each statement represents an item and each item is included in a dimension. This model of satisfaction evaluation is based on a theoretical model where there are 5 dimensions, each one including between 4 and 6 items, an each item can be only in one and only one dimension.

The idea is to compare the average scores of each item and each dimension:

```
(score dimension = sum (items))
```

I think that my problem is multiple, but I would like roughly to export several tables of this type:

```
Dimensions  Lieu 1  Lieu 2  Lieu 3
N   Score moyen N   Score moyen Significativité (versus Lieu 1) N   
Score 
moyen   Significativité (versus lieu 2)
Réactivité  322 4,39    181 4,24    *   170 4,24    *
Le temps d'attente  338 4,46    188 4,30    *   176 4,28    *
L’attention portée  325 4,35    187 4,29    ns  172 4,16    *
différence significative au seuil 1%, ** différence significative au 
seuil 5%, * différence significative au seuil 10%, ns différence non 
significative.
```

The right test is the Wilcoxon / Mann Whitney test (non-normality verified by the Shapiro Wilk test). My problem is that I cannot create a table with all average scores, N and significant tests

I tried several things:

- A tapply for the average scores but I cannot extract the "N" (or the NA) when I calculate them
- A CreateTableOne to extract the most complete table possible but I still do not have the N and the Wilcoxon test does not allow to know which modalities are compared (done with kruskal.test). Moreover, when I want to use this test, it transform all averages into medians because the variables do not follow a normal distribution.
- An export with write.table that seems to work:

---

```
VARIABLES SUIVENT UNE LOI NORMALE ?
temps_attente_1 <- subset(enquete2, lieux == "Lieu1",temps_attente)
temps_attente_2 <- subset(enquete2, lieux == "Lieu2", temps_attente)
shapiro.test(temps_attente_1$temps_attente)
shapiro.test(temps_attente_2$temps_attente)

TEST DE WILCOXON / MANN WHITNEY
temps_attente_1w <- as.numeric(temps_attente_1 [,1])
temps_attente_2w <- as.numeric(temps_attente_2 [,1])
wilcox.test(temps_attente_1w, temps_attente_2w)


CALCUL DES MOYENNES PAR SOUS GROUPE DE TEMPS ATENTE
m=tapply(enquete2$temps_attente, enquete2$lieux, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
m
          Lieu 1             Lieu 2             Lieu 3 
          4.058894           4.131250           4.283333 


CREATETABLEONE 
library(tableone)
library(survival)
dput(names(enquete2))
vars_tot <- c("dim_reactivite", "temps_attente", "attention", "lieux")
tab_1 <- CreateTableOne(vars=vars_tot, strata= "lieux", data=enquete2, testNonNormal = kruskal.test)
tab_1

                          Stratified by lieux
                           Lieu1         Lieu2         Lieu3       p  

    test
  n                             245            92            41                          
  dim_reactivite (mean (sd))   4.06 (0.67)   4.13 (0.43)   4.28 (0.58)         0.144     
  temps_attente (mean (sd))    3.84 (1.00)   3.27 (1.00)   4.11 (0.84)        <0.001     
  attention (mean (sd))        4.22 (0.86)   4.45 (0.74)   4.26 (0.78)         0.074     
  lieux (%)                                                                <0.001     
 Lieu1                     245 (100.0)     0 (  0.0)     0 (  0.0)                  
 Lieu2                       0 (  0.0)    92 (100.0)     0 (  0.0)                  
 Lieu3                       0 (  0.0)     0 (  0.0)    41 (100.0) 

tab_2 <- print(tab_1$ContTable, smd=TRUE, showAllLevels=TRUE, quote=FALSE, noSpaces=TRUE)
                              Stratified by lieux
                               Lieu1       Lieu2       Lieu3       p      test    SMD
  n                            245         92          41                                  
  dim_reactivite (mean (sd))   4.06 (0.67) 4.13 (0.43) 4.28 (0.58)        0.144       0.263
  temps_attente (mean (sd))    3.84 (1.00) 3.27 (1.00) 4.11 (0.84)        <0.001      0.588
  attention (mean (sd))        4.22 (0.86) 4.45 (0.74) 4.26 (0.78)        0.074       0.199

variante avec variables non normales
items <- c("dim_empathie", "horaires_rec", "proximite_rec", "non_jugement_rec", "tout_dire_rec")
tab_2 <- print(tab_1$ContTable, nonnormal= items, smd=TRUE, showAllLevels=TRUE)
                                 Stratified by lieux
                                  Lieu1             Lieu2             Lieu3             p       test     SMD
  n                               245               92                41                                      
  dim_reactivite (median [IQR])   4.25 [3.69, 4.50] 4.25 [3.75, 4.25] 4.25 [3.81, 4.75]   0.258 nonnorm  0.263
  temps_attente (median [IQR])    4.00 [3.00, 5.00] 3.00 [3.00, 4.00] 4.00 [3.00, 5.00]  <0.001 nonnorm  0.588
  attention (median [IQR])        4.00 [4.00, 5.00] 5.00 [4.00, 5.00] 4.00 [4.00, 5.00]   0.080 nonnorm  0.199

EXPORT DANS UN TABLEAU EXCEL
write.table(cbind(VARIABLES=row.names(tab_2), tab_2), file="U:/HAITI/EVENEMENTS/2018/2018_01_29_ENQUETE_SATISFACTION/test2.xls",dec=",", row.names=F, col.names=TRUE, sep ="\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few items you can try.

1. I have a dataframe (myDF_sans_deletion) that is organized like this
   (this is just a small sample):

> ```
> Protein  Condition  Optical_Density  Replicate
> Pch1     RR      0.6809166667     Replicate_1
> Pch2     RR      0.8679166667     Replicate_1
> Pch3     RR      1.2815166667     Replicate_1
> Pch4     RR      0.6538166667     Replicate_1
> Pch5     RR      0.4396166667     Replicate_1
> Ggle     RR      0.9845166667     Replicate_1
> TemP     RR      1.3857166667     Replicate_1
> TemP     RRΔl    1.9347           Replicate_1
> Pch1     RRΔl    2.1332           Replicate_1
> Pch2     RRΔl    2.3168           Replicate_1
> Pch3     RRΔl    2.2212           Replicate_1
> Pch4     RRΔl    2.0262           Replicate_1
> Pch5     RRΔl    0.5013           Replicate_1
> ```

If I would like to find the max, mean, variance, standard deviation, and standard deviation of the Optical_Density column, I can manipulate the dataframe this way and save it to a new dataframe called stats_sans_deletion.

```
stats_sans_deletion <- ddply(myDF_sans_deletion, .(Protein, Condition), summarize, max_OD = max(Optical_Density), mean_OD=mean(Optical_Density), variance_OD=var(Optical_Density), SD_OD=sd(Optical_Density), SE_OD=sd(Optical_Density)/sqrt(length(Optical_Density)))
```

2. If I were interested in doing some statistical test, I could do the following:

```
dt_result = myDF_sans_deletion %>% group_by(Protein) %>% do(tidy(t.test(Optical_Density~Replicate, data=., var.equal=F)))
```

3. If you are having issues with na.rm=T, consider removing them from your original dataframe, then go on to what you want to do.

Again, you will need to play around with this a bit, and there is more than one way to do something.